# Input field string linked to mysql db that loads with the page and saves on edit?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to create a favorites section on my website where users have an option to add a note near their favorited items. The note would be entered into an input field, and I would like for the data to load with the webpage and update on change. Notes will be stored in the database where all favorited items are stored.

I was wondering what is the best approach to take to accomplish this?

This is what I was thinking:
Pull the 'note' string from the database and set it as the 'value' of the input field.

On Change: I am not exactly what the best way is to recognize the change and update the database and this is what I hope to get help with.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can either submit a PHP form with method `POST` and handle the addition with a PHP script or send the note by AJAX post. **I suggest jQuery to those unfamiliar with AJAX**. Here's an example:

```
$.post("save-note.php", { note: $("#note").val() })
```

If you would like to save when they finish typing, it could work like this:

```
$(".note").blur(function() {
    var edited_note = $(this);
    $.post("script-to-add.php", { note: edited_note.val() })
});
```

Comment: script-to-add.php is the script php that actually updates the database?

Comment: Thank you. I know what AJAX is. I am just trying to understand the method above. What does 'note: ' do, in your example?

Comment: Sorry if I came off as condescending. I thought you meant you didn't understand JavaScript object notation. Note is passed as a post parameter in this example.